# How to unjoin viewport in blender 3.6?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I lost my mesh because I accidentally join it with another viewport. Now in my layout section there is no mesh. It is only the viewport that I joined my mesh that is showing but in another section like sculpting I can still see my mesh.

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what's happening, maybe press "/" in the 3D scene to exit Local view if you've enabled it accidentally?

Comment: Please add an image of your current Blender screen. You can create a screenshot from Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu and then edit your question and add your image into it. I suspect you'll just need to split your screen and then select the 3D view again from the menu but without seeing an image it's difficult to tell.

Comment: The other option might be Alt-H, unhide. In Object and Edit Modes, both.